# Hover function on nav item not working

Tags: jquery, menu, navigation, slidedown

I have the following hover script that is supposed to handle the sliding down and up of sub menus in my navigation bar:

```
$j('body').ready(function() {
    $j('.menu-item').hover(function() {
        $j(this).find('.sub-menu').slideDown("slow");
    },
        function() {
            $j(this).find('.sub-menu').slideUp("slow");
        });
});
```

It slides down fine, but for some reason it doesn't slide up, but rather just disappears when leaving the div.

You can see the nav item in action on [this page](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk/), specifically on the 'news' item, which has a dropdown for an events page.  You will need to enter the following credentials as the site is under development:

username:guest

password:stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('.menu-item').hover(function() {
        $j(this).find('.sub-menu').stop().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

you should position the element relatively:

```
.sub-menu {
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: i don't think there is an issue, because he said that `slideDown` works fine

Comment: Note that changing the `body` selector to `document` will make no difference - you can select any element and the `ready` event handler will always execute on DOM ready.

Comment: Same result with this script I'm afraid, div just disappears. As I've used the script from the original question in other situations, I'm a bit perplexed.

Comment: No, that doesn't help I'm afraid.  The nav item already has position:absolute due to the default css of the Wordpress theme I am using: `#nav ul, #nav .sfhover ul ul, #nav :hover ul ul {left: -9999px;position: absolute;}`

Comment: @Nick surely the problem is related to CSS.

Comment: well, yes, I'd say so, but I've no idea what CSS.  I have created a child theme for Wordpress, so I am using a custom CSS file to override the default CSS.  So, it's probably something to do with the default CSS, but it seems strange to me that slideDown would work fine, but not slideUp.

Answer (score 0):

```
$j('.menu-item').mouseover(function() {
    $j(this).find('.sub-menu').slideDown("slow");
});
$j('.menu-item').mouseout(function() {
    $j(this).find('.sub-menu').slideUp("slow");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but with this I get a slide up and down repeating when I hover over the div